# How can I align text with the twitter button?

Tags: html, css

how can I align the text with the twitter button?

This is how I want it to be aligned:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
            <p>text <b>text</b> <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.1357735024.html#_=1358118140271&amp;id=twitter-widget-0&amp;lang=it&amp;screen_name=test&amp;show_count=true&amp;show_screen_name=true&amp;size=m" class="twitter-follow-button" style="width: 214px; height: 20px;" title="Twitter Follow Button" data-twttr-rendered="true"></iframe>
              <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
            </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind providing a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) CSS property appears to be what your looking for.

Here's a [working example of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/X4YRA/) I made.

Comment: @Kaos yes you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SfNns/ (upvote my comment if this helped please)